# Why setting register_globals in PHP is a security hole?

Tags: php, xampp

I am a bit of confused after going through different articles on `PHP's register_globals`.

I know that, if you have register_globals turned ON, then anything passed in a GET or POST gets automatically translated into a variable in PHP and acts as global variable but still whats the harm doing that(though knowing it can override the variable).

> I exactly want to know list of what all harm it can cause, if set to ON?
>
> If its harmful then Why XAMPP has set it to ON, by default?

I have already gone through different discussions on the stackoverflow but still looking for some explanatory answer.

Thanks.

Comment: For your technical question regarding XAMPP configuration, please consult the techsupport they offer. All I know is that setting it to ON is not the accepted PHP configuration setting by *php.net* project. The PHP manual also has decent resources about that setting and reasoning: [Using Register Globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)

Comment: thanks for your comment @hakre, I have already gone through the different discussion but still looking for some good technical answers here which could really define the things well and explain the things around.

Comment: Well, what should I add? You've read already so much online about it, it's perhaps time you start reading a book then? Or if it's just that written media doesn't explain it well to you, you might be looking for a tutor?